# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound getting this

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

Jun 26, 2022 5:27:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' getting this in console, server is getting startup successfully, but the http://localhost:8080/hello/ http://localhost:8080/greeting/ is not loading , could you pls help..

```
            Controller class
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
            @Controller
            public class SimpleController {
            @RequestMapping("/hello")
            public String hello() {
                
                return "index";
                
            }
            @RequestMapping("/greeting")
            public ModelAndView greet() {
                
                
                ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("greet"); 
                mav.addObject("greeting", "Hi this me");
                    
                    
                return mav; 
                }
                
            }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

web.xml->
SpringMVC

```
   <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>  

 
</web-app>  
spring-servlet.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  
  
    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc" />  
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>  

</beans>  

greet.jsp-->
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p>Hi</p>
${greeting}
</body>
</html>

 -->index.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p>Hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the maven dependyncy in your project
Right Click on yout project > properties > select Dependency Assembly tab
choese Add -> add Maven Dependency

Comment: Maven dependecy are added in the path as told above, maybe some other issue

Comment: no i dont have any other controller..

Comment: in spring-servlet.xml      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>, the jsp view  files must be addd in this path /WEB-INF/views   folder

Comment: yes they are in this folder ..

Answer (score 0):

you should try http://localhost:8080/hello ,with out the last backslash

Comment: still same issue..

Comment: if you  still don't resolve the problem,you chould pass your project to the github,then we can check and fix it.

Comment: sure pls find the link https://github.com/geek12312/Spring/tree/master

Comment: the problem is solved in my mac, you should move spring-servlet.xml to the src/main/resources .

Comment: When i moved it to src/main/resources getting this now
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved by adding jstl jar in the lib path. Thanks for your answers and support.